# Undefined function 'num2str' for input arguments of type 'double'

Tags: matlab, double

I'm trying to use num2str in a load function as follows

```
route=3;
samples=1;
pct=100;

path('C:\')
load(['B2A_Sample_r',num2str(route),'_',num2str(pct),'%_',num2str(1000+samples)])
```

I also tried:

```
filename=char(['B2A_Sample_r',num2str(route),'_',num2str(pct),'%_',num2str(1000+samples)]);
load(filename,'-mat')
```

I'm having to shut down and reboot matlab every time I get this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are clearing your [path](http://www.mathworks.com/help/search.html?qdoc=path&submitsearch=Search) each time you run, so MATLAB can't find any files or functions, whether built-in or not (including `num2str`). Each time it tries, it only looks in `C:\` and then gives up. Try this:

```
route=3;
samples=1;
pct=100;
filename=char(['B2A_Sample_r',num2str(route),'_',num2str(pct),'%_',num2str(1000+samples)]);
directory = 'C:\';

fullfilename = fullfile(directory,filename);

load(fullfilename);
```